# Union of python dicts while keeping tuple of values

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have two python dictionaries that contain tuples as key and floats as values so that they appear as

```
dict1 = {(name1,name2):data1a, (name2,name3):data2a, ...}
```

and

```
dict2 = {(name1,name2):data1b, (name2,name3):data2b, ...}
```

The dictionaries are not of the same length and I would like to perform a union of them, based on their keys, so that I am left with a single dictionary that has a tuple of the values from both. This would appear as

```
dict_unified = {(name1, name2) : (data1a,data1b), (name2,name3) : (data2a,data2b)}
```

I know that `dictionary.update()` effectively does this merge but it would include key value pairs that only exist in a single dictionary, which I want to exclude, and would only keep one values for each key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a dict comprehension :

```
{key: (value1, dict2[key]) for key, value1 in dict1.iteritems() if key in dict2}
```

This keeps the keys that are common to `dict1` and `dict2` and merges their values in a tuple.

Comment: Yes this works just as I had hoped. I wanted to avoid looping and hoped there may be an `intersection()` function as there is for sets. It didn't take long to run however, because of hashing

Answer (score 0):

To get the keys that belong to both dictionaries, you can use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) (as this an intersection, not a union):

```
>>> d1 = {(1, 2): 3, (4, 5): 6}
>>> d2 = {(1, 2): 7, (8, 9): 10}
>>> set(d1).intersection(d2)
{(1, 2)}
```

Then build a dictionary with the corresponding values from both dictionaries:

```
>>> {k: (d1[k], d2[k]) for k in set(d1).intersection(d2)}
{(1, 2): (3, 7)}
```